# onHandleIntent - Wallpaper change not working correctly when app is closed

Tags: android, live-wallpaper, android-intentservice, android-wallpaper

I am using the IntentService to change wallpaper in the background. It gets invoked on receiving of a push notification. Below code works fine if notification is received while the application is open. But does not work if the Application is closed/killed (by swiping it away with help of menu button)

```
@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {

    //Toast.makeText(this, "Intent", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences(MyPREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

    String imageUrl = intent.getExtras().getString("imageUrl");

    try {
        URL url;
        try {
            WallpaperManager myWallpaperManager = WallpaperManager
                    .getInstance(MySingletonClass.mainActivityInstance);


            url = new URL(
                    imageUrl);
            Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(url
                    .openConnection().getInputStream());
            myWallpaperManager.setBitmap(bmp);


        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    PushReceiver.completeWakefulIntent(intent);
}
```

Works fine when the application is opened. When closed/killed, it isn't able to create instance of WallpaperManager and throws below exception.

```
W/System.err: java.lang.NullPointerException
W/System.err: at android.app.WallpaperManager.getInstance(WallpaperManager.java:361)
```

Comment: Did you define `Service` on `manifeste`.

Comment: Yes it is defined in Manifest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using `MySingletonClass.mainActivityInstance` which was actually null as pointed by @qbix, Use context of the IntentService which is `this`.

```
try {
        WallpaperManager myWallpaperManager = WallpaperManager
                .getInstance(this);


        url = new URL(
                imageUrl);
        Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(url
                .openConnection().getInputStream());
        myWallpaperManager.setBitmap(bmp);


    }
```

Answer (score 1):

When an app is swiped from the list of recent tasks, the process for the app is killed and its memory reclaimed. All the app components (activities, services, providers, singletons, etc.) no longer exist.

In the situation you describe, after the app is swiped and its process killed, a push notification is received. This appears to be handled by a `WakefulBroadcastReceiver` which starts your service. At that point, the service is the only active component in your app. No instance of MainActivity exists.  Unless you have code you have not posted here that performs other app initialization,  MySingletonClass is null and/or mainActivityInstance is null.

Comment: Right, that's the reason for failing. How can I achieve it ? I want to change wallpaper on receiving of the push notification. Can you point me to some working piece of code? Thanks.

Comment: Hi Thanks for hint. I solved it by using `this` instead of `MySingletonClass.mainActivityInstance`

Answer (score 0):

```
public class MyReceiver extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // Explicitly specify that MyIntentService will handle the intent.
        ComponentName comp = new ComponentName(context.getPackageName(),
                MyIntentService.class.getName());
        // Start the service, keeping the device awake while it is launching.
        startWakefulService(context, (intent.setComponent(comp)));
    }
}

public class MyIntentService extends IntentService {

    public GcmIntentService() {
        super("MyIntentService");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
      // do some stuff
    }
  }
```

**Manifests Code:**

```
   <receiver android:name=".receiver.MyBroadcastReceiver" >
     <intent-filter>
     </intent-filter>
   </receiver>

  <service android:name=".receiver.MyIntentService" />
```